# Getting a strange error on my routes, "missing required keys" rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

So I am getting this error on my localhost:3000.  I am making a gif posting blog app and I am trying to add an edit function to items that appear in my _feed_item.html.erb partial.  I have posted the error below and a link to some source files in a gist.  I believe the routes are ok, but the "missing required keys: [:id]" piece is the one aspect I don't understand.  Not sure why this doesn't work as well as my delete function does.  Some of this code is based on Hartl's rails tutorial.

app/views/shared/_feed_item.html.erb where line #25 raised:

No route matches {:controller=>"microposts", :action=>"edit"} missing required keys: [:id]

Extracted source (around line #25(see the bold line below)):

```
</span><br />

<% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
    **<%= link_to "edit", edit_micropost_path %>**
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete, 
                data: { confirm: "Are you sure? "}, title: feed_item.content %>
<% end %>
 </li>
```

[Link to Gist](http://bit.ly/OggH8i)

Comment: Use `rake routes` output to see the computed routes.  I'm guessing your route may need to be pluralized.  edit_microposts_path

Comment: edit_micropost GET    /microposts/:id/edit(.:format) microposts#edit  When I changed to the plural form I got a new error, undefined local variable or method `edit_microposts_path', so I don't think that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your're almost there. The error message says,

`No route matches {:controller=>"microposts", :action=>"edit"} missing required keys: [:id]`.

The controller has to know which resource (micropost) you are trying to access. Give the id of the resource and you'll be all fine.

```
**<%= link_to "edit", edit_micropost_path(feed_item.id) %>**
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your edit path a parameter so it knows the id of the micropost to edit.

```
edit_micropost_path(feed_item)
```