# Rails 4 acts_as_votable No route matches / missing required keys error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the acts_as_votable plugin and I keep getting this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"upvote", :controller=>"posts", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I am following the answer from this SO question:  [acts_as_votable thumbs up/down buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012276/acts-as-votable-thumbs-up-down-buttons)

I tried adding .id to the view as suggested here:  [Getting a strange error on my routes, "missing required keys" rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851964/getting-a-strange-error-on-my-routes-missing-required-keys-rails-4) but then I get this error:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

here is my code:

post_controller:

```
def upvote
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.liked_by current_user
  redirect_to @post
end
```

routes:

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    get 'like' => 'posts#upvote', as: :upvote
  end
end
```

view:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.user.name %><BR><BR>
  <%= post.post_content %><BR><BR>
  <%= link_to "like", upvote_post_path(@post), method: :put %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have:

```
<%= link_to "like", upvote_post_path(post), method: :put %>
```

The error occurs because you're supposed to use `post` block variable, while you try to use `@post` instance variable, which is unset and thus evaluates to `nil`.

Comment: Thank you!  When I get to 50 rep i will add a note to the original question I referenced in case others run into this problem.  I will choose your answer in 10 minutes when it lets me.